# how to do autocomplete search working with input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, input

i need jquery or javascript to do autocomplete drop-down list with the results of my search typing.. i need the result as link "" so i can open it in new tab or open it directly by click on it.
here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="searchinput" class="search-input" placeholder="Search here.." />

<ul id="main-menu">   
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Menu Header1</span></a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">brand one</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">brand two</span></a></li>
       </ul>    
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Menu Header2</span></a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car BMW</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Toyota</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Opel</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Kia</span></a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it with jQuery UI Autocomplete Features. check demo at here... and make changes as your requirement in your code.[https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories]. I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: thnx Bharat for replay .. but as i'm beginner so i didn't understand what i have to do :(

Comment: Sorry for late replay. You just include jQueryUi Plugin and update this demo as your requirement.

Comment: @BharatMakvana thank you and i founded the answer and added it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution with @MatusDubrava script and some other help here..

```js
$(function () {
                            var menuPages = $('#main-menu li a:has(.childtitle)').map(function () {
                                return {
                                    label: $(this).text(),
                                    value: $(this).attr('href')
                                };
                            }).toArray();
                            $("#txt_MenuSearch").autocomplete({
                                source: menuPages,
                                select: function (event, target) {
                                    /* On select, show item's label in text input */
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    $("#txt_MenuSearch").val(target.item.label);
                                    var link = target.item.value;
                                    window.open(link);
                                },
                            });
                            /* Highlight text */
                            $("#txt_MenuSearch").data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                                var newText = String(item.label).replace(
                                    new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
                                    "<span style='color:#DDBA15'>$&</span>");

                                /* Wrapping the matching option within <a> tags */
                                newText = '<a href="' + item.value + '">' + newText + '</a>';

                                return $("<li>")
                                .attr("data-value", item.value)
                                .append(newText)
                                .appendTo(ul);
                            };
                        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt_MenuSearch" class="search-input" placeholder="Search here.." />

<ul id="main-menu">   
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Menu Header1</span></a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">brand one</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">brand two</span></a></li>
       </ul>    
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="title">Menu Header2</span></a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car BMW</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Toyota</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Opel</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="example.com"><span class="childtitle">Car Kia</span></a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution in plain JavaScript.

- create array of tags agains which you will match the input
- set `input` event listener for the input field
- on each `input` event, clear contents of list element and based on some matching function, create new one dynamically, adding
  link for each matched string

```js
// array of values to match against
const tags = ['bmw', 'toyota', 'opel', 'kia'];

// fetch input and list elements
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');

// simple match function, performs substing matching
const getMatch = (toMatch, tags) =>
  tags.filter((tag) => tag.includes(toMatch.toLowerCase()));

input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  // clear contents of list
  list.innerHTML = '';

  // start matching only when input field is non-empty
  if (input.value !== '') {
    // call matching function and create a link for each
    // item returned by it
    getMatch(input.value, tags).forEach((match) => {
      const item = document.createElement('li');
      list.append(item);

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      item.append(link);

      // add href attribute and text dynamically
      link.setAttribute('href', `www.example.com/${match}`);
      link.textContent = match;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
Search: <input type="text">
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: thank you very much @Matus but i have three things missing with this code .. first i need the result to appear like dropdown list under the input with marker of letters i writing .. second i need the result to get it's own href link as it in `<a>` element like example1.com & example2.com etc.. finally is that possible to target the the result with `class="childtitle"`

Comment: @MuhammadS.Eltyar `result to appear like dropdown list under the input`, no need to change this code, just use css to style `ul` and `li` elements that way.  `result to get it's own href link` they do have their own links, but if you need that exact format then change `.forEach((match)` to `.forEach((match, idx)` and `www.example.com/${match}` to `www.example${idx+1}.com` and to add a class to those newly created links, add `link.className = 'childtitle';` line to the bottom of `forEach` block.

Comment: thank you very much.. but you didn't get what i need ..
First.. i don't need to add class to newly created links but i need to get all items with class `'childtitle'` in my html code above instead of static array as you mentioned in you code `const tags = ['bmw', 'toyota', 'opel', 'kia'];` because i need it to get the pages names dynamically from the ul menu.
second.. need to get there `href` attribute for example "brand one" page have  url `href="example.com"` and "brand two" page have url `href="google.com"` etc..
**appreciated your help in advance @Matus**